# How can i handle a Java internal memory access using JNA

Tags: java, java-8, jna

the c code is

```
extern int APIENTRY LSGetDocData(
    short          hConnect,
    HWND           hWnd,
    unsigned long  *NrDoc,
    LPSTR          FilenameFront,
    LPSTR          FilenameBack,
    LPSTR          Reserved1,      // not used must be NULL         
    LPSTR          Reserved2,      // not used must be NULL
    LPHANDLE       *FrontImage,
    LPHANDLE       *BackImage,
    LPHANDLE       *Reserved3,     // not used must be NULL
    LPHANDLE       *Reserved4,     // not used must be NULL
    LPSTR          CodelineSW,
    LPSTR          CodelineHW,
    LPSTR          BarCode,
    LPSTR          CodelinesOptical,
    short          *DocToRead,
    long           *NrPrinted,
    LPVOID         Reserved5,      // not used must be NULL
    LPVOID         Reserved6);
```

and my Java method is

```
public int LSGetDocData(
    short hConnect, 
    int hWnd, 
    long[] NrDoc, 
    String FilenameFront, 
    String FilenameBack, 
    String Reserved1, 
    String Reserved2, 
    int[] FrontImage, 
    int[] RearImage,
    int[] FrontImage2, 
    int[] RearImage2, 
    StringBuffer CodelineSW, 
    StringBuffer CodelineHW, 
    StringBuffer Barcode, 
    StringBuffer CodelinesOptical, 
    short[] DocToRead, 
    long[] NrPrinted,
    int Reserved5,
    int Reserved6);

public int lSGetDocData(long[] nrDoc, int[] frontImage, int[] rearImage, StringBuffer micrHW, StringBuffer barcode, StringBuffer micrSW, StringBuffer codeLineOptical) {    
        return LsApi.call.LSGetDocData(hConnect[0], hWnd, 
            nrDoc, "imageF", "ImageR", null, null, 
            frontImage, rearImage, null, null,
            micrSW, micrHW, barcode, codeLineOptical,
            new short[0], new long[0], 0, 0);
}
```

the error is

```
Exception in thread "StartCapture" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:426)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.LSGetDocData(Unknown Source)
```

This code works perfectly using IBM Java 1.6 32 bits... but we want to use Oracle Java 1.8 32 bits and we get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Your type mappings are not correct, and it is possible that the IBM JDK handled pointers to memory for some objects (arrays, `StringBuffer`s) in a different manner than Oracle, permitting these incorrect mappings to appear to work.

Some specific notes:

- `long` in Java is 64 bits, but `long` can be 32-bits or 64-bits in C.  You state you're using a 32-bit JRE but not what the operating system bitness is.  `NativeLong` can handle this difference.
- `HWND` is mapped in JNA, extending `HANDLE`, which is pointer-sized. On 32-bit systems, `int` works, but you should use `HWND` for portability.
- similarly, `LPHANDLE` is mapped to `HANDLEByReference`, a pointer to a pointer-sized value.
- JNA Handles the mapping of `String` to C Strings, but I'm not sure about `StringBuffer`. This could be a source of the problem.
- JNA does not handle 0-sized arrays well.  I suspect the `new short[0]` or `new long[0]` may be causing problems, as you're defining a pointer to an empty allocation.  Does the native code attempt to write something here?

In summary, on 32-bit (or any bitness of Windows) the `long *` mapping is wrong, or on 64-bit the `HWND` and `LPHANDLE` mappings are probably wrong (depending on pointer size).  The `StringBuffer` mappings might be suspect.  And 0-size arrays cannot be written to (so perhaps `null` is appropriate there).

Comment: I'm using windows 10 64 bits... so i must use NativeLong ???.

Comment: What should i do with 0-sized arrays ??? set to null ??

Comment: Passing a null pointer can not be any worse than passing a pointer to a null array.  As for 64 bit windows -- `long` is actually always 4 bytes on windows so you can use `int` there. Not `long`. `NatvieLong` is always good cross-platform, but Windows uses 32-bit `long`.

Comment: So with 64-bit windows the native `long` is 32-bits so `int[]` works for the pointer mapping if you have a native array, or a `Pointer` to a memory allocated object is more general purpose if the API does not specify an array. `hWnd` is a 64-bit pointer, `HWND` is best here.  `LPHANDLE` is definitely `HANDLEByReference`.

Comment: ok.. i changed it:

public  int LSGetDocData(short hConnect, int hWnd, int[] NrDoc, String FilenameFront, String FilenameBack, String Reserved1, String Reserved2, int[] FrontImage, int[] RearImage,
        int[] FrontImage2, int[] RearImage2,byte[] CodelineSW,byte[] CodelineHW, byte[] Barcode, byte[] CodelinesOptical, short[] DocToRead, long[] NrPrinted,
        int Reserved5, int Reserved6);

Comment: public int lSGetDocData(int[] nrDoc2, int[] frontImage2, int[] rearImage2,  byte[] micrHW2, byte[] barcode2, byte[] micrSW2,byte[] codeLineOptical2) {
    return lsDispatch.LSGetDocData(hConnect[0], 0, nrDoc2, "imageF", "ImageR", null, null, frontImage2, rearImage2, null, null, micrHW2, micrSW2, null, null, null,null,0, 0);

but i still got the same error... any thoughts ?? thanks in advance

Comment: You still have `int` for the handle. That's pointer-sized,  Use the JNA `HWND` mapping. And use `HANDLEByReference` for the `LPHANDLE` mappings.  There are probabaly better mappings than the primitive arrays you are using but without seeing the full API you are mapping, I can't tell you more.